# How do I fix this "paddle jump" glitch in my code?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

http://pastebin.com/YTiNw7rX

If you test the code out, Pushing the paddle all the way up to the top of the screen, and let it go, the paddle jumps down a few pixels. And I can't seem to figure out how to fix this. I would imagine it has something to do with the texture.

Edit: Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens:

1. You hold the key.
2. The functions checks and/or adjusts the current `Y`.
3. The function updates the current `Y` according to your key press.
4. The current `Y` is displayed on the screen.
5. You let go of the key.
6. The functions checks and/or adjusts the current `Y`.
7. The corrected `Y` is displayed on the screen, causing a jump from the previous `Y`.

So, you will want to update your current `Y` **before** the check, not after it.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allow the game to exit.
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    // Update the paddles according to the keyboard.
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        PongPaddle1.Y -= paddleSpeed;

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        PongPaddle1.Y += paddleSpeed;

    // Update the paddles according to the safe bounds.
    var safeTop = safeBounds.Top - 30;
    var safeBottom = safeBounds.Bottom - 70;

    PongPaddle1.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(PongPaddle1.Y, safeTop, safeBottom);
    PongPaddle2.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(PongPaddle2.Y, safeTop, safeBottom);

    // Allow the base to update.
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```